# Find Two Points In A Three-Dimensional Space Nearest To Each Other

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

As the title suggests, I'm working on a homework assignment where we are limited to using multi-dimensional arrays in order to create a program that finds two points nearest to each other in a three dimensional space. So far my code looks like this (hybridized from examples in my textbook and my own code):

```
package exercise7_7;
public class Exercise7_7 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of points:");
    int numberOfPoints = input.nextInt();

    double[][]  points = new double[numberOfPoints][3];
    System.out.println("Enter " + numberOfPoints + " points:");
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        points[i][0] = input.nextDouble();
        points[i][1] = input.nextDouble();
        points[i][2] = input.nextDouble();         
    }
    int p1 = 0, p2 = 1, p3 = 2;
    double shortestDistance = distance(points[p1][0] , points[p1][1] , points[p1][2] ,
            points[p2][0] , points[p2][1] , points[p2][2]);

    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < points.length; j++) {
            double distance = distance(points[i][0] , points[j][0] , points[j][1] , points[j][2] , points[i][2] , points[j][2]);

            if (shortestDistance > distance) {
                p1 = i;
                p2 = j;
                shortestDistance = distance;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The closest two points are " + "(" + points[p1][0] + "," + points[p1][1] + 
        and (" + points[p2][0] + "," );
}
public static double distance(
        double x1, double y1, double z1, double x2, double y2, double z2) {
    return Math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)) + ((z2 - z1) * (z2 - z1)));

  }
}
```

What I mostly need help with is figuring out just how to get these points compared. I don't think the way I tackled this problem was the best way to do it.

Thanks for the help guys. I'm running on 2 hours of sleep for 2 days now so please excuse any stupid questions or sloppy code.

```
                                     ******
```

I think I've got it:

```
package exercise7_7;
public class Exercise7_7 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of points:");
    int numberOfPoints = input.nextInt();

    double[][]  points = new double[numberOfPoints][3];
    System.out.println("Enter " + numberOfPoints + " points:");
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        points[i][0] = input.nextDouble();
        points[i][1] = input.nextDouble();
        points[i][2] = input.nextDouble();         
    }
    int p1 = 0, p2 = 1;
    double shortestDistance = distance(points[p1][0] , points[p1][1] , points[p1][2] ,
            points[p2][0] , points[p2][1] , points[p2][2]);

    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < points.length; j++) {
            double distance = distance(points[i][0] , points[j][0] , points[j][1] , points[j][2] , points[i][2] , points[j][2]);

            if (shortestDistance > distance) {
                p1 = i;
                p2 = j;
                shortestDistance = distance;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The closest two points are " + "(" + points[p1][0] + "," + points[p1][1] + "," + points[p1][2] + 
            ") and (" + points[p2][0] + "," + points[p2][1] + "," + points[p2][2] + ")");
}
public static double distance(
        double x1, double y1, double z1, double x2, double y2, double z2) {
    return Math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)) + ((z2 - z1) * (z2 - z1)));

}
}
```

Input is taken in, processed, and then outputs the two closest points. Just as a reference, when:
(-1,0,3),(-1,-1,-1),(4,1,1),(2,0.5,9),(3.5,1.5,3),(-1.5,4,2),(5.5,4,-0.5) are inputted, the outcome 
seems to be (-1,0,3) and (4,1,1). Could someone confirm that for me.

If this isn't the way to follow up on my own question, I apologize. First day on these slopes and I'm still
learning the ropes.

Comment: Okay, you've clearly making an attempt on your own, but you haven't explained what the problem is or where you're stuck. Cutting this down may make it easier to understand what's happening.

Comment: Do you have to store the `Point` in an `Array` too? It would be much more obvious if you had a `ThreeDPoint` class that had `X`,`Y` and `Z` properties.

Comment: I don't have to store the point in an array. I just need to figure out which set of points are the closest to each other. 

To chrylis: I'm stuck at the portion where I compare all the points and figure out which set of points are the closest. I was thinking of hard coding the points just to make it easier on myself but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: To cut down on some math you could use `dx = x2-x1`, etc, additionally, as you're only concerned in which are closest, and not the actual distance, you can skip the sqrt and simply compare the sum of the squares.

Comment: I don't see any problems and the algorithm is sound, what's the issue?

What I can see at the moment is that the call to distance isn't the same as the function signature you defined for distance.

double distance = distance(points[i][0] , [points[j][0] , points[j][1] , points[j][2]);

distance(
        double x1, double y1, double z1, double x2, double y2, double z2)

Comment: Do you worry because you are using an O(n^2) algorithm?

Comment: Fixed up the code just a bit. I addressed the issue that Pork called out and I also fixed it up for the "double distance" line. I can run it now and the program takes input from the user and processes the points but the outcome isn't proper. I'm thinking it has something to do with the part where the program remembers the closest points.

Comment: @Doestovsky For future reference, `@` tag someone if you want them to get a notification; I just happened to stumble back across this question.

Comment: Your method call is wrong I think `distance(points[i][0] , points[j][0] , points[j][1] , points[j][2] , points[i][2] , points[j][2]);` should probably be `distance(points[i][0] , points[j][0] , points[i][1] , points[j][1] , points[i][2] , points[j][2]);`. Another thing is that you already calculate the distance between `0` and `1` before you enter your loop so you can loop from `i=1`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thank you for catching that. Changed up the result of the outcome on the example but it's looking good now I think.

Comment: That is exactly the reason why best practice states that if a method has more than two parameters you are doing something wrong...

Answer (score 2):

Use a `class` to represent your points. This way to you have a `distanceTo` method that calculates and returns distance. Also you can have a `toString` method that prints out the point for display to the user. Taking your code rearranging yields this class:

```
public class ThreeDPoint {

    final double x;
    final double y;
    final double z;

    public ThreeDPoint(final double x, final double y, final double z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public double distanceto(final ThreeDPoint other) {
        final double dx = other.x - x;
        final double dy = other.y - y;
        final double dz = other.z - z;

        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{X=" + x + ",Y=" + y + ",Z=" + z + "}";
    }
}
```

Now putting that together gives this, which is much more readable. I have removed the bit where you read points and used random numbers:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    final ThreeDPoint[] points = new ThreeDPoint[5];
    final Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
        points[i] = new ThreeDPoint(random.nextInt(100), random.nextInt(100), random.nextInt(100));
    }
    //store min
    double min = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    int first = -1;
    int last = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < points.length; ++j) {
            final double d = points[i].distanceto(points[j]);
            if (d < min) {
                min = d;
                first = i;
                last = j;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The minimum distance is between point " + first + " and " + last + "(" + points[first] + " and " + points[last] + "). This distance is " + min + ".");
}

private static final class ThreeDPoint {

    final double x;
    final double y;
    final double z;

    public ThreeDPoint(final double x, final double y, final double z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public double distanceto(final ThreeDPoint other) {
        final double dx = other.x - x;
        final double dy = other.y - y;
        final double dz = other.z - z;

        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy + dz * dz);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{X=" + x + ",Y=" + y + ",Z=" + z + "}";
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't mean to be a jerk since it looks like you practically handed me the solution, but there's an error in the 3rd line that's keeping me from running it: cannot find symbol "class Random". The code looks perfectly sound so I'm thinking it's an issue on my end.

Comment: This should work, but the code that finds the two points is unsophisticated. You could create another class that has two of these points and is comparable, populate an array with every combo then sort them - the first element would be the two points. Your algorithm is O(n*n), but sorting is O(n log(n))

Comment: @Bohemian, how would I populate the combinations array on less than O(n^2) time?

Comment: You don't need to populate both directions of the pair, since `distance(x, y) == distance(y, x)`, so the inner loop would loop from 1 to the outer index, not size. The key word is *combinations*, not *permutations*.

Comment: Quite so. I didn't notice that `int j = i + 1` :)

Comment: @Doestovsky, you need to import [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).